# MySQL : Insert Data With Single Query, But Auto Increment Number On Non-Auto Increment Column

Tags: php, mysql

I have this SQL query :

```
INSERT INTO db1.outbox (DestinationNumber, TextDecoded)
SELECT User.CellPhone, '$SMSMessage' as TextDecoded
FROM db2.User
WHERE User.PurchaseDate BETWEEN 2012-01-01 AND 2012-01-31
```

it does multiple rows insertion to 'outbox' table. and I can easily get the ID number of first row by using this query :

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

and let's say I have 532 as result from `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and I have 34 rows inserted.

how to use this 532 as initial number for other table named 'outbox_multipart' insertion and having it auto increment so the result will be like this :

```
+------+----------------+----------+----------------------------------+
| ID   | phonenumber    | outboxID | message                          |
+------+----------------+---------------------------------------------+
|                      ......                                         |
| 1025 | 555-123456     | 532      | part 2 : hello there!            |
| 1026 | 555-999999     | 533      | part 2 : hello there!            |
| 1027 | 555-888888     | 534      | part 2 : hello there!            |
|                                                                     |
|               ...... 34 rows inserted here .......                  |
|                                                                     |
+------+----------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

please note that outboxID column isn't auto increment column. but it must have auto increment number from 532 + 34 rows = 566.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
ALTER TABLE outbox_multipart AUTO_INCREMENT = 532;
```

it will increments from the 532,

and remember that the "outboxID" should also be in auto increment initially

Comment: how to stop it until 34 rows? or will it automatically stop when no other rows inserted, so that when I have another insertion process, let's say, started with 821... I have to ALTER TABLE again, but this time start with 821. is that what you mean? make sense to me...

Comment: NO not like that once you perform this query then it initially starts from 532,and after if your insertion starts from 821,then it will auto incrementing  "outboxID" from 821 thats it,otherwise it will starts from 532+34 = "566"

Comment: ok, got it... +1 for you and accepted as an answer, thank you.

Comment: I thought he said outboxID column wasn't autoincremented? @Guatam, will this allow him to insert an ID that is out of order. Say the last insertion in outboxID was 566 and he went to insert 700 there? I thought it would autoincrement to 567 instead of allowing him to insert a specific value and increment from there. Just trying to learn.

Comment: Not like that @ FajitaNachos as i mentioned,if he wants to insert 700 then he performs the query then the auto increment value should be 700 right..??then it starts at 700 until the new auto increment value will be given thats it

Answer (score 0):

What about using a for loop combined with number of affected rows in mysql. If you are using PDO(which I reccommend) you can use this  http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

So it would look something like this.

```
<?php 

 $dbh = new pdo (your_database_connection_details);
 $stmt = dbh->prepare() //do your initial insert into the outbox table
 $stmt->bindParams() //bind your parameters
 $stmt->execute();

 $out_box_id =  dbh->lastInsertId();
 $row_count = dbh->rowCount();

for(x=0;x<$row_count;x++){   
  //insert $out_box_id into the outboxID column
  $stmt->execute();
  $out_box_id = $out_box_id + 1;
 }
```

So this should grab the last inserted id of your first insert and set the $out_box_id to it. Then you can insert $out_box_id inside your for loop. The loop with run however many times the number of rows inserted was and then at the end of each loop it will increment the out_box_id by one.